# fill, border not working for kineticjs Text object on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, kineticjs

I have updated to 4.4. I'm initializing a Text object like this:

```
var droppableText = new Kinetic.Text({
            x : posX,
            y : posY,
            name : field,
            stroke : '#555',
            strokeWidth : 2,
            fill : '#ddd',
            text : text,
            fontSize : fontSize,
            fontFamily : 'Calibri',
            textFill : '#555',
            width : width,
            height : height,
            padding : padding,
            align : 'center',
            fontStyle : 'italic',
            shadow : {
                color : 'black',
                blur : 10,
                offset : [10, 10],
                opacity : 0.2
            },
            cornerRadius : 10
        });
```

It seems to get the X, Y and text position correct, but there is no background or border like there was before. This was working before when I was using version 4.0, I just updated to 4.4 and now it doesn't work.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, the border rectangle has been gone since version 4.3.0

https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/wiki/Change-Log

```
Big changes to Kinetic.Text shape. 

Rectangle component has been removed to simplify the API. textFill is now fill, textStroke is now stroke, textStrokeWidth is now strokeWidth, and textShadow is now shadow. 

If you want to have a rectangle behind the text, you need to group the text with a Kinetic.Rect shape. Text fontSize units are now in pixels (used to be in points). The lineHeight attr is now defaulted to 1 (used to be defaulted to 1.2).

cornerRadius attr moved to rect shape
```